# Codeigniter: URL solutionless problem

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-2

I have following url:

http://localhost.com/phpdemo/bid/tf/red?

This url redirects through This  [ $route['tf/red?'] = "abc/blue" ] to following url:

http://localhost.com/phpdemo/bid/abc/blue

Till now there is no problem. The problem starts when I attach some value with "?" like below:

http://localhost.com/phpdemo/bid/tf/red?a    [It always go to default welcome page]

I have tried follwoing routes:

```
$route['tf/red?(:any)'] = "abc/blue"

$route['tf/red?:any'] = "abc/blue" 

$route['tf/red?(a-zA-Z0-9=)'] = "abc/blue"
```

I have tried following config settings:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z A-Z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
```

I also checked by using following:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Now Iam clueless, what is wrong, either with Codeigniter or myself.

Can some one guide me in this regards.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the value of $config['uri_protocol'] - it is set in the main config.php file and the default is 'AUTO'.

Try each of the possible values to see which works for you - PATH_INFO or REQUEST_URI are common choices.